# Does errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name work for source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, dead-letter

Does `"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name"` work for source connector? I tested with [JDBC sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html) and it works, but I don't find a record which has serialization error goes to dead letter queue.

I use [Debezium Connector for MongoDB](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/mongodb.html) and [apache-kafka-connect](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect) version is 2.4.0.

The rest error handling config:

```
"errors.tolerance": "all",
"errors.log.enable": "false",
"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "test-dlq",
"errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[apache-kafka-connect](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect) has included error handling options, including the functionality to route messages to a *dead letter* queue since Apache Kafka 2.0 through [**KIP-298**: Error Handling in Connect](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-298%3A+Error+Handling+in+Connect). According this KIP, Dead Letter Queue is *[supported](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-298%3A+Error+Handling+in+Connect#KIP-298:ErrorHandlinginConnect-DeadLetterQueue(forSinkConnectorsonly)) for Sink Connectors only*.

Also you can check Kafka Connect [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation.html#sinkconnectconfigs):

> **errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name**: The name of the topic to be used as the dead letter queue (DLQ) for messages that result in an error when processed by this *sink connector*, or its transformations or converters. The topic name is blank by default, which means that no messages are to be recorded in the DLQ.

---

Great article about [**Error Handling and Dead Letter Queues**](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/) by [*Robin Moffatt*](https://www.confluent.io/blog/author/robin-moffatt)